# Parsing All Mail from Mailbox File in Python

Tags: python, email, parsing

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but I want to parse a single "catch all" email inbox via Python. I see the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html) module and I can make it parse an individual email, but what I want to do is open (for example) /var/spool/mail/catchall and parse all of the individual messages inside it. Opening that file and running the parser over it treats the whole thing as one giant email. How would I break it into individual messages?

Alternatively: is this A Bad Idea, given I'm going to want to delete the messages when I'm done with them? I'm tying this route instead of POP/ IMAP only because the server support isn't available right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`mailbox`](http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html) to actually go through the mailbox.